# Deadlock MS-SQL when Inserting Into a Table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, multithreading, deadlock

I am using the following query to insert in the respective historical table changes occurred to a given table. I am executing the same query simultaneously for multiple tables in python (changing the table name and database). None of the historical tables have foreign keys. But some of the executions end up in deadlock. Each table have assign a unique historical table. I am not sure how to solve the issue. Is it because I use a variable table with the same name in all the procedures?

```
declare @name_tab table (name_column varchar(200),
                       dtype varchar(200))
declare @columns varchar(max)
declare @query varchar(max)
declare @database varchar(200)
declare @table_name varchar(200)
set @database = '%s' 
set @table_name = '%s'

insert into @name_tab
select c.name as name_column,
        t.name as dtype
from sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t
    ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = @table_name

set @columns= stuff((select ','+name_column from @name_tab FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '') 

set @query= 'insert into ' +@database+'..'+'HISTORY_'+@table_name+' select super_q.* from' +
        '(select cast (GETDATE() as smalldatetime) as TIME_MODIFIED, new_info.* from '+
        '(SELECT ' + @columns + ' From '+@database+'..'+@table_name + 
        ' except ' +
        'SELECT ' + @columns + ' From '+@database+'..'+'HISTORY_'+@table_name + ') new_info) as super_q'

          execute(@query)
```

I got this sample from system_health
[image]

Comment: Check the system_health trace file target for deadlock event details .

Comment: Using the same variable name would not cause a deadlock. Are there any other processes accesign this DB while the insert is happening?

Comment: There are other processes referencing  sys.all_columns on the same database at the same time @PiotrS

Comment: I was using 10 threads, so I could have up to 9 other processes accessing the DB while the insert is happening to execute their own insert into other historical tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that some concurrent process is altering or creating a table at the same time.  The deadlock XML should contain additional details about what's going on.

But whatever the actual cause, the solution is simple.  Use your scripting above to generate the trigger bodies in static SQL so you don't have to query the catalog for every insert.

Create a procedure in your database called, say, `admin.GenerateHistoryTables` and one called `admin.GenerateHistoryTriggers` and run those *ahead of time* to install the history tables and wire up the triggers.

Or stop re-inventing the wheel and use [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) or [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017).